# How can I render the bundle options in product list

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, bundled-product

How can I render the bundle options in product list

I tried to add the block

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('bundle/catalog_product_view_type_bundle', '', array('template'=> 'bundle/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/options.phtml'))->toHtml(); ?>
```

inside the `list.phtml` for each bundled product in `$_productCollection` but its not working.
Do I need to create a module with blocks having methods of catalog and bundle modules?
I am new to Magento. Please help. I tried everything I can.

Answer (score 2):

That is not an easy issue, mostly because of complex JavaScript. It is not used to list of bundles and I'd recommend to write own js library to present bundle options.
Don't waste time and efforts trying to fix or reuse magento library.

There are a lot of examples how to take options. (http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-get-bundled-items-by-bundle-product/)

Render them itself.

Comment: I found this link for displaying configurable options in product list 
http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/display-multiple-configurable-products-with-options-on-one-page-in-magento/comment-page-1/
is it possible to display bundled products with some changes? .
I only have 3 bundled products to sell. so should I just render 3 products using for each with predefined product id's in an array in the view.phtml

Comment: Sure you can, all depends on requirements you have, don't hesitate to hardcode if you feel that the issue could not be so hard, sometimes OOP is en evil.